# Custom function not working on pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string, function

I have a dataset with a column like this:

```
0        534K
1      482.2K
2      491.3K
3      247.6K
4      815.3K
        ...  
144    403.4K
145      1.3M
146      3.1M
147    311.5K
148      3.7M
```

I'm trying to clean the column values by writing a function like this (to remove the 'K's and '.' as a test first):

```
def fix_column(val):
    i = 0
    if val[i][-1] == 'K' and len(val[i]) == 4:
        val.replace("K","")
        val = val + "000"
    elif val[i][-1] == 'K'and len(val[i]) == 5:
        val.replace("K","").replace(".","")
        val = val + "00"
    i += 1
    
    return val
```

But when I try to apply the function on the column like `df.col = df.col.apply(fix_column)` nothing happens and the column values remain unchanged. If I do something like `df.col = df.col.apply(lambda x:x.replace("K","").replace(".",""))` I do get close to a desirable output like so:

```
0       534
1      4822
2      4913
3      2476
4      8153
       ... 
144    4034
145     13M
146     31M
147    3115
148     37M
```

I may be missing something basic but would appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first mistake is to use a loop at all. Your second mistake is to use a loop incorrectly. (`i` is a local variable, its value is always 0.) Here's a way to go:

Separate the number and the decimal suffix (if any):

```
number_strings = df.col.str.extract('([\d\.]+)([MK]?)')
```

Convert the number strings into proper numbers:

```
numbers = number_strings[0].astype(float)
```

Multiply the numbers, where necessary:

```
numbers[number_strings[1] == 'K'] *= 1,000
numbers[number_strings[1] == 'M'] *= 1,000,000
```

Paste the results back into the dataframe:

```
df.col = numbers
```

Comment: I was just writing an answer with the same method so glad you did that, it can be perhaps more succinctly put: `df.col.apply(lambda x: str(int(float(x[:-1]) * 1000 if x[-1] == 'K' else 1000000 if x[-1] == 'M' else 1)))`

Comment: @Nick One should stay away from lambda if a non-lambda solution is possible.

Comment: Probably true. Depends on circumstance... in this case it would probably be faster because it's not using a regex extract. Anyway, I upvoted...